# Use EasyBCD to create dual-boot Ubuntu 13.04 and win 8

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, easybcd

I just installed ubuntu 13.04 alongside win 8; The problem is: There is no boot option. it will directly go to win 8. So I do research and find solution is something about 'grub', I dont want too use grub yet, I am very new to Ubuntu, so I prefer to use EasyBSD. And now, how to use EasyBCD correctly ?? please look:

[image]

and this:

[image]

Correct me if I wrong: I `add New Entry` and then select tab `Linux/BSD` and then I stuck. Which `Type` and `Drive` I have to choose ??

Thanks.

Comment: The Windows Boot Loader cannot boot ELF binaries. As such, you need another boot loader. One of the options for that is Grub. I also don't see what's wrong with it...?

Answer (score 1):

**TYPE**  According to the Ubuntu documentation, [Ubuntu 13.04 by default uses grub 1.99, or Grub 2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing).  So, when it asks for the TYPE, you choose Grub 2.

**DRIVE**  Now, I don't know the details as to which you installed first (Ubuntu or Windows) or where you installed Grub (to the main drive/partition, or the linux one) but we should assume that for Drive, you need to choose Partition 6, or the Linux one.

Comment: Thanks. I installed Windows 8 first then Ubuntu in Partition 6, it' only show `BASH-Like supported ... blablaabla ... grub>`, and then nothing. What I have to do to entering ubuntu? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution to your problem will be using Boot-Repair.Run Ubuntu live cd.Open terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

And press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now type `boot-repair` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> once again. Use *Recommended repair. It will do the job.

Comment: So, what exactly will it do? What will be the result?

Comment: You will get boot option on startup for both Windows 8 and Ubuntu.