# Not able to dual boot windows 8.1 and ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-8.1, easybcd

I installed ubuntu in a laptop already installed with windows 8.1. But while booting it does not give an option to boot into ubuntu. So I tried with easy bcd. The boot menu is not showing ubuntu. So I added ubuntu from the add new entry tab.

In the examples given by easy bcd, the partition with linux must be labelled as 'Linux'. In my case it is Partition 9. It is labelled as 'HFS'. Anyway I selected this partition and added as the new entry.

When rebooted it gave me two options - windows 8.1 and Ubuntu. But when I select ubuntu , it showing an error 'The application or operating system cannot be loaded because a required file is missing or may contain errors.

Any idea on what could be the issue will be extremely helpful. I am struggling on this for quite a bit of time. Please help

I had asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978906/not-able-to-dual-boot-windows-8-1-and-ubuntu) with screenshots. I cannot post pictures here because  dont have enough reputation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use EasyBCD to create dual-boot Ubuntu 13.04 and win 8](http://superuser.com/questions/599875/use-easybcd-to-create-dual-boot-ubuntu-13-04-and-win-8)

Comment: Is EasyBCD UEFI/GPT capable ? New computers come with Windows 8.1 on GPT/UEFI so I don't see how EasyBCD would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

New computers come with Windows 8.1 installed on UEFI firmware and GPT style disks.

Windows boot manager on UEFI cannot boot foreign systems like Linux (is not allowed to boot or was designed not to boot). At least as of today nobody has found a way to force Windows UEFI boot manager to boot (chain load) Linux.

You can install Ubuntu on a UEFI firmware and GPT disk without problem as long as you have free disk space. (BOOT Ubuntu CD/DVD/USB the UEFI WAY !)

Ubuntu/GRUB can chain load Windows 7/8 on UEFI (and BIOS) so after installing Ubuntu you will have a GRUB dual boot menu "Windows 8.1 + Ubuntu".

Check also [BootNext utility](http://www.boyans.net/bootnext/bootnext.html) which allows direct booting of Linux(Ubuntu, Fedora) from Windows 7/8.1.

Setting the default loader or boot manager can be done in firmware and so you can choose to set either Windows or Ubuntu to be the default boot loader/manager.

Another alternative is using [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) boot manager which can chain load Windows and Linux/GRUB.

Answer (score -1):

NOTE: this going to delete everything on your Hard disk.

I suffered from this issue when I have bought my Lenovo laptop that was pre installed with win 8, I have an easy solution for you in case you don't have valuable data on your LAPTOP/PC.

The reason why you can't dual boot is your hard partition table use GPT format not MBR format. You have to convert it from GPT > MBR by doing this.

1. Boot from any Linux distribution that has Gparted pre installed in the live CD.
2. Open Gparted -> Click on create new partition table -> select MBR format -> then click OK/APPLY.
3. After that install Windows 8/7, just make sure install Windows first then install Ubuntu.

You will notice that the boot loader is working now. I think there may be other solutions but they may be more complex.

Comment: Ubuntu is capable of UEFI and GPT. You don't need to do this!

Comment: More complex than deleting all data?

Answer (score -1):

Cuase you've installed ubuntu then installed Windows 8 your ubuntu boot damaged! You should repair ubuntu boot! Below is very simple solution! You should consider that if you're PC is 64bit System should boot with 64bit live mode and if your is 32bit your live disk should be 32bit ubuntu!
[How to repair ubuntu boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)

Comment: According to the question Ubuntu has been installed after Windows. (Or did I understand it wrong?)

Comment: We expect more then a link to another website, even another Stack Exchange website, here at Superuser.

Comment: @user3865434 windows is already installed. Ubuntu was installed after that. I tried boot repair also. It didnot work.

Comment: @user2907250 What boot repair?